# NugGet package installing a class file instead of assembly

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

I've installed a NuGet package that instead of adding assemblies and references, it puts an un-compiled class file in the packages directory.

What is the proper way of consuming the class such that it can still be managed by NuGet for updates etc?

Structure for reference:

```
SolutionDir
    |
     -Packages (nuget)
         |
          - ContentDir (cs file here)
    |
     -ProjetDir (the project that needs it)
    |
     -OtherProjectDir
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the class is part of the package, it will be updated during the package update as long as the class has not been modified. If it has been modified, it's going to be left as-is. NuGet will output a warning stating so during the update.

I'd compare the two files, maybe with NuGet Package Explorer, to see if missing any functionality. I believe it'll have to be done manually at the moment.

Comment: Ahh so moving it into the required project is a manual process at this point?

Comment: If you modify a file, it won't be removed at uninstall or touched on update.
But if you move the code file the new one should be copied over because there won't be a collision. That could help you, but yeah you'll have to manually compare the files I think.